# Restarting sound files in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, restart

stop();

```
var mySound:Sound = new MyFavSong();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var lastPosition:Number = 0;
myChannel = mySound.play();

    pause_btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPause);

        function onClickPause(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        lastPosition = myChannel.position;
        myChannel.stop();
    }

    play_btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickPlay);

        function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);
    }
```

I am trying to make a restart button however everything I have read is not correctly working on bringing it back to the start of the sound. I am not really great with flash so I made it as simple as I could. Any and all help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and that's the correct way to implement a pause/play method in as3.

That means the problem is elsewhere. Print lastPosition at the start of your onClickPlay function. Is it printing something other than 0?

- Take this as a comment. This thing only lets me post answers.